# Converting java code to c++

Tags: java, c++

How do I convert the below piece of java code to C++. I know I can write 
`typedef unsigned char byte` so that is taken care of, but I don't understand what the `|=` and `<<=` are meant for. And how does one replace `final`

```
public static final long unsignedIntToLong(byte[] b) {
          long l = 0;
          l |= b[0] & 0xFF;
          l <<= 8;
          (l >>> 4) & 0x0F;
```

How do I test all this in C++ - are there some unit tests I can run as I go about the conversion.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything; there's no return statement.

Comment: And |= and <<= are identical in Java and C++, and the 'final' in 'static final long <method>' does precisely nothing. There is in fact no question here.

Comment: This code is more or less useless in C++. C++ already has a built-in `unsigned int` so there is no need to use an array of bytes. if you have a variable `unsigned int x;` and you need to convert it to `long`, you just do: `long y = (long)x;`, which is much simpler.

Comment: got it. This program accepts a data feed that is in different formats. this program is almost meant to serve the purpose of a hex editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing, `|=` is a compound bitwise OR assignment. `a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b`, where each resulting bit will be set if either that bit in `a` or `b` is set (or both).

Here's a truth table that is applied to each bit:

```
a | b | result
--------------
0 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 1
```

Secondly, `<<=` is the same, but instead of a bitwise or, it's a bit shift to the left. ALl existing bits are moved left by that amount, and the right is padded with 0s.

```
101 << 1 == 1010
110 << 2 == 11000
```

`final` is the same as C++'s `const` by the variable definition. If, however, you want to prevent a function from being overriden, you may tag `final` onto the end of the function header if the function is also a virtual function (which it would need to be in order to be overriden in the first place). This only applies to C++11, though. Here's an [example](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#final) of what I mean.

Finally, `>>>` is called the `unsigned right shift` operator in Java. Normally, `>>` will shift the bits, but leave the leftmost bit intact as to preserve the sign of the number. Sometimes that might not be what you want. `>>>` will put a 0 there all the time, instead of assuming that the sign is important.

In C++, however, `signed` is an actuality that is part of the variable's type. If a variable is signed, `>>` will shift right as Java does, but if the variable is unsigned, it will act like the unsigned right shift (`>>>`) operator in Java. Hence, C++ has only the need for `>>`, as it can deduce which to do.

Comment: `final` is not the same as `const` in this context.

Comment: +1, you can't restrict C++ classes not to be extended in any way.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, oops, I didn't notice that. I was a bit still stuck on the other two. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I've changed the `final` bit now (no pun intended). Please don't tell me they removed that like they did with extern templates :p

Comment: @chris, I just added an extra line of code, is that meant to be a bitwise >. can you post an example of how that would work. thanks,

Comment: @user1155299, it probably would have fit better in a new question (and there's probably one out there), but I've updated my answer.

Comment: @chris, got it. thanks! btw, if you don't mind me asking, do you primarily code in java or c++ or both.

Comment: @user1155299 I'm an avid C++ programmer; I started actually going through a Java book a few weeks back, instead of meaning to learn it, but not doing anything. All of the programs I use for purposes other than learning have been C++ to this point.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12083/discussion-between-user1155299-and-chris)

Answer (score 3):

|= is the same in both languages: bit-wise OR applied to the lhs variable, just like +=.  Same with <<=; it's the shift bits left operator.

Unsigned long could be tricky; no such thing in Java.

There's CppUnit.  Try using that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight answer on how to write a final class in C++. Google will show you a lot of examples though. For example a private constuctor or a frend class.

| is the OR operator. So for example 0x10 | 0x10 = 0x11.

<< is the bitshift operator. So for example 0b1 << 0b1 = 0b10, 10 << 2 = 0b1000 and so on. Shifting by 1 multiplies your value by 2.

For example:

```
class Converter{
public:
    static Converter * createInstance()
    {
        return new Converter;
    }

    long unsignedIntToLong(unsigned char *b){
        long l = 0;
        l |= b[0] & 0xFF;
        l <<= 8;
        //..
        return l;
    }
private:
    Converter(){

    }
};
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, perhaps you could show some sample code on how the `final` will work. My code posted is not complete as I am still trying to understand what the different pieces are doing. This code is meant to decode a data feed that is not in ASCII format